# Is there a way to keep the opened items of a Nested Tree even after updating or reloading

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a nested tree data structure as presented in the link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcv63x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

my goal is to keep the selected tree items in opened state even after refreshing.

At first I tried to collect all the tree items that are selected into another variable so that we can give back this list to app component.

But i'm not able to find solution to process this expanded list.

Answer (score 0):

If for refreshing you mean refreshing all the browser page I suggest you to use localStorage to save the object in a persistent way.

```
localStorage.setItem('tree', JSON.stringify(this.sampleData) // Save your items

this.sampleData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tree')); // Get your items when you load the page
```

Comment: Thanks, it is both updating the data with more inputs or browser refresh

Comment: no, i didnt solve it ..